# Existence of $\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> **Exercise** Assume that $K$ and $A$ are disjoint nonempty subsets of $
> \Bbb{R}^n$ with $K$ compact and $A$ closed. Prove by using wat we know about $d(x,A)$ that there exists $\delta >0$ such that $||x-a||\ge\delta$ for all $x\in K$ and $a\in A$.
>
> **What we know about $d(x,A)$**: The function $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R^n}$

It was easy to show that $d(x,A)$ is indeed uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}^n$ and because $A$ is closed $A=cl(A)$ thus for $x\in K$ and $x\not\in A$ we get $d(x,A)\not=0$ which means that there exists $\delta > 0$ st $d(x,A)=\delta>0$. Dus $\inf\{||x-a|| : a\in A\}=\delta$ in other words $||x-a||\ge \delta$ for all $a\in A$. Is this correct?

Comment: Where did you use compactness?

Comment: i'm not sure i have, that's why i posted this "proof" for verification. Apologies for not making this clear in my OP

Comment: While the distance between any two points in the two sets (even the distance between a point in one set and the entirety of the other set) are always positive, that does not mean that there is a $\delta > 0$ that bounds the distances between the sets. Think about the distance between the sets $A = \{(a, 1/a)\mid a \in \Bbb R^+\}$ and the positive $x$-axis. For any point $x_0$ on the $x$-axis, $d(x_0, A) \geq 0$. Yet the distance is not bounded below, and can get as close to $0$ as you wish. You need to use compactness to prove that this isn't the case here.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is closed and $K$ is compact, they both include their boundaries, so if for some $x\in K$, $d(x,A)=0\iff x\in \overline{A}$, but then $x\in A$, this is a contradiction.

So indeed $d(x,A)\gt 0$.

Consider $d(\cdot,A):K\to \Bbb R^+$, since $d$ is uniformly continuous it maps compact sets to compact sets, thus the image $d(K)$ is compact, so there is some $\delta\gt 0$ such that $d(x,A)\ge \delta,\forall x\in K$.

Just to note that $d(x,A)=\inf_{a\in A}\|a-x\|_\infty\ge\delta\gt 0,\forall x\in K \Rightarrow \|x-a\|_\infty\ge\delta,\,\forall x\in K$.

You can also argue that a continuous function on a compact set must attain its minimum and maximum.

Comment: A function doesn't have to be _uniformly_ continuous to map compacts onto compacts.

Comment: indeed, continuous is enough, I just meant implicitly uniform cont$\Rightarrow $ cont.

Answer (score 0):

A direct proof:

Since $A$ is closed for every $z\in A^{c}$ (hence every $z\in K\subset A^{c}$)
there is some $\delta_{z}>0$ s.t. $\left\Vert z-a\right\Vert >\delta_{z}$
is true for each $a\in A$.

For $z\in K$ define open set $U_{z}:=\left\{ y\mid\left\Vert y-z\right\Vert <\frac{1}{2}\delta_{z}\right\} $.

Then $K\subset\bigcup_{z\in K}U_{z}$ and because
$K$ is compact there is a finite set $F\subset K$ s.t. $K\subset\bigcup_{z\in F}U_{z}$.

The finiteness of $F$ guarantees that $\delta:=\frac{1}{2}\min\left\{ \delta_{z}\mid z\in F\right\} $
is positive.

If $x\in K$ and $a\in A$ then we find some $z\in F$ s.t.
$x\in U_{z}$.

Assumption $\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert <\delta$
leads to $\left\Vert z-a\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert z-x\right\Vert +\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert <\frac{1}{2}\delta_{z}+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{z}=\delta_{z}$
wich is not true.

This allows us to conclude that $\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert \geq\delta$.